# React axios.get not working it's says failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, axios

I am new in React . I am trying to get my api data with **axios** . But getting error . My code are :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import ApiContent from './ApiContent';

class App extends React.Component{
    axios.get('http://example.com/api/api/topCardNews')
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="asdfs">
                <ApiContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

And Getting the errors Lists of :

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/index.js
>   Syntax error: Unexpected token (7:7)
>
> 6 | class App extends React.Component{
>
> 7 |  axios.get('http://example.com/api/api/topCardNews')
>
> 8 |    .then(function (response) {
>
> 9 |      // handle success
>
> 10 |      console.log(response);
>
> ```
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
> ```

Comment: you are attempting to call a function inside a class declaration. put your function call inside the class constructor or a class instance method.

Comment: @DanO I am sorry for that let me try this with constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i have to use this api code inside any `Javascript event` or `constructor()`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import ApiContent from './ApiContent';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        axios.get('http://example.com/api/topCardNews')
          .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
          })
          .then(function () {
            // always executed
          });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="asdfs">
                <ApiContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Put call function inside constructor or componentDidMount function like

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     axios.get('http://example.com/api/api/topCardNews') //...
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      //or here or to other lifecycle function based on needs
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="asdfs">
                <ApiContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling the axios.get(.....) in either life cycle events (like ComponentWillMount) or Constructor.

A class component can either have declarations or function definitions along with render. It cannot have direct call to a function.